# Java - code always throw NullPointerException

Tags: java

This code throws a NullPointerException.

```
protected static Integer cost;
public static int incCost(int value)
{
   cost += value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the default value of reference types is `null`, not `0`.

```
protected static Integer cost = 0; //<-- add = 0
```

Or, use a primitive `int` like

```
protected static int cost; //<-- defaults to 0.
```

You also must return an `int`, so you could do

```
public static int incCost(int value)
{
   cost += value;
   return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you never initialized cost, you would need to do

```
 protected static Integer cost = 0;
```

becuase you cant add a number to an uninitialized object;